# Does shut your door sound ruder than close your door?

Tags: meaning

I am wondering does "shut the door" sound ruder than "close the door"?
For example, shut your mouth, which is rude.Therefore, I am not sure whether shut brings the meaning into the phrase "shut the door" as well?

Comment: The word "shut" might be considered slightly ruder than "close" because of the kinds of connotations you point to. But it is very weak. Both "close the door" and "shut the door" used on their own seem to me to be equal in terms of propriety. Both can be used rudely or politely, depending on one's tone. Usually, they are embedded in requests like "Would you shut that door, please?" When embedded, any negative connotations are defeated (IMO).

Comment: The abrupt vowel sound "u" and hard consenant "t" in "shut" could be construed as having a harsh tone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions of shut and close are essentially the same. There is something about shut though that has more of a bite, at least in this scenario: imagine you are trying to be quiet to stay hidden, and you whisper to someone "close your mouth". Doesn't sound so bad, right? But most would agree that saying "shut your mouth" in the same scenario, while conveying the very same meaning, would somehow seem a bit more harsh. To me personally, using shut seems to suggest youre more concerned for concealing your own location, while close seems a bit more open to wanting to protect both of you. Maybe the harshness all circles back to the fact that the phrase "shut your mouth" or "shut up" is widely considered to be derogatory. I'm not sure though.

If you phrase either one as a question, it will inevitably sound much better than either as they're currently phrased.

And that pretty much goes for anything. "Give me water." Sounds much more rude than "Can i have water?".

Answer (score 0):

"Shut the door" would be less polite in the imperative than "close the door", although only marginally, but would not be considered rude if used descriptively as in, "He shut the door." or if embedded as noted in the comment above by Silenus.